# Converting an integer to date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, format

I have a numerical column called OpenDate which displays e.g ‘16042014’ for ‘16/04/2014’ and I want to convert this into a date with the format of 16/04/2014. So when exported into excel, excel can recognise the date and filter accordingly. Currently it exports as an integer 16042014.

Comment: what kind of sql are you using ? Mysql, msql server, oracle etc?

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL ISO Standard this is done by the following expression :

```
CAST(SUBSTRING(MY_COL FROM 5 FOR 4) || '-' || SUBSTRING(MY_COL FROM 3 FOR 2) || '-' || SUBSTRING(MY_COL FROM 1 FOR 2), AD DATE)
```

But very often it depends of your real SGBDR (Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2...)

As an example, with SQL Server you can use the DATEFROMPART cionstructor :!

```
DATEFROMPARTS(MY_COL % 10000, MY_COL % 1000000 / 10000, MY_COL / 1000000)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: read my answer with the new entry please